# print output in csv file python

Tags: python, csv

My code that is used to print the output of the pcap file IP's IN CSV FILE is working well but the issue is it is storing only 1st packet of the pcap file. I am not getting where is the actual issue is..
can someone help me to solve this then please.

Here is my code:

```
import dpkt
from dpkt.ip import IP
from dpkt.ethernet import Ethernet
import struct
import socket
import csv

def ip_to_str(address):
    return socket.inet_ntoa(address)

f = open('sample.pcap', 'rb')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
        continue

    ip = eth.data
    do_not_fragment = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_DF)
    more_fragments = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_MF)
    fragment_offset = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_OFFMASK)
    c = csv.writer(open("a.csv", "wb"))

    Source = "%s" % ip_to_str(ip.src)
    Destination = "%s" % ip_to_str(ip.dst)
    Length = "%d" % (ip.len)
    TTL = "%d" % (ip.ttl)
    OFF = ip.off
    TOS = ip.tos
    Protocol = ip.p
    data = (Source, Destination, Length, TTL, TOS, OFF, Protocol)
    c.writerow(data)
```

Comment: fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid there is no eror of indentation. its working well but there is issue that it only printing the 1st packet of pcap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is currently opening a csv file inside the loop, so each time creating a new version of "a.csv" and only writing one packet to it. Move the file creation statement outside of the loop, and keep writing inside the loop.

```
import dpkt
from dpkt.ip import IP
from dpkt.ethernet import Ethernet
import struct
import socket
import csv

def ip_to_str(address):
    return socket.inet_ntoa(address)

f = open('sample.pcap', 'rb')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
c = csv.writer(open("a.csv", "wb"))  # <=== moved here
for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
        continue

    ip = eth.data
    do_not_fragment = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_DF)
    more_fragments = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_MF)
    fragment_offset = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_OFFMASK)

    Source = "%s" % ip_to_str(ip.src)
    Destination = "%s" % ip_to_str(ip.dst)
    Length = "%d" % (ip.len)
    TTL = "%d" % (ip.ttl)
    OFF = ip.off
    TOS = ip.tos
    Protocol = ip.p
    data = (Source, Destination, Length, TTL, TOS, OFF, Protocol)
    c.writerow(data)
```

Comment: thanks for your interest. But when i used your editing in my code. It don't even writing single packet to csv. I don't know why. can you help

Comment: You need to close the file at the end of the loop.

Comment: Can you check again? It is working for me as-is. I tried a sample pcap from the web on this, and the csv gets created and populated fine for the whole pcap. Maybe see if you can add some prints in your code to make sure the loop is actually... looping :-)
 @Burhan Khalid I think in python you can get away without having to explicitly close files.

Comment: @sal i have checked your editing and its not working for me i don't know where is the issue :(

Comment: Couple of more questions for you: python2 or python3? Is there a way you can share the pcap? Can you try this: comment the `c.writerow(data)` line and put instead a `print data` statement, and see if that prints all (or any) packets on screen?

Comment: using python 2 and i hav downloaded sample pcap from internet .. and when am using print command it perfectly prints all the packet in the output.. i can try to share my pcap if you can tell me ur mail id ....

Comment: Any luck with the prints?

Comment: dear @sal i dint got you sorry.

Comment: In the code with my mods, can you try this: comment the c.writerow(data) line and put instead a print data statement, and see if that prints all (or any) packets on screen?

Comment: yes when i used print data statement it prints all the packet on the screen

Comment: Great! I was running out of ideas on what else could be wrong. :-)

Comment: there is one more issue that i want to get print headers with this data.. headers = "Source, Destination, Length, TTL, TOS, OFF, Protocol"          can you tell how it can be print in csv along data

Comment: and also when am copying the same working code of csv to new file it gives the following error. WHy so ???   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/ip csv.py", line 6, in <module>
    import csv
  File "C:/Python27\csv.py", line 11, in <module>
    c = csv.writer(open("a.csv", "wb"))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'

Comment: For your first question, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. For a quick way, you can do `headers = ["Source", "Destination", "Length", "TTL", "TOS", "OFF", "Protocol"]` and do a `c.writerow(headers)` right before the `for` loop.
For the second, you need to rename your file from `csv.py`, as that is clashing with the `csv` module. See stackoverflow.com/questions/18069181/python-csv-has-no-attribute-writer in particular the answer by @thameera

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you close the file at the end of your loop; and as mentioned indent your code properly:

```
import struct
import socket
import csv

import dpkt

from dpkt.ip import IP
from dpkt.ethernet import Ethernet

def ip_to_str(address):
    return socket.inet_ntoa(address)

with open('sample.pcap', 'rb') as f:
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

results = []
for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
        continue

    ip = eth.data
    do_not_fragment = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_DF)
    more_fragments = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_MF)
    fragment_offset = bool(dpkt.ip.IP_OFFMASK)

    data = [ip_to_str(ip.src),
            ip_to_str(ip.dst),
            ip.len,
            ip.ttl,
            ip.off,
            ip.tos,
            ip.p]
    results.append(data)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer.writerows(results)
```